# Best Way to Surface Dynamic SQL Queriability

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, dynamic-sql

I'm looking into refactoring a screener solution (a "screener" being the kind of highly flexible and customizable filtering that sites like Amazon, Newegg or Revzilla support).

Currently, screeners are populated as tables with several hundred columns, and we have an old C# app which is responsible for formatting and escaping a serialized representation of the query arguments into a string of dynamic SQL, which is then passed into a procedure to be executed and retrieve the filtered data. The solution works fine for all exact matches, but without going into too much detail, wildcard searches could not be escaped in a way which was flexible enough for our purposes.

But looking into refactoring it, I realize I'm not really sure what the best approach to this is. The first thought I had was have the C# application construct a parameterized query. I could then add an arbitrary number of `SqlParameter` objects to the command, and use good old-fashioned `quotename()` and `sp_executesql`. But that still feels hacky. The data set isn't huge, so storing it in memory and using linq or something also seemed viable, but I don't know how you would do "dynamic linq".

**My question is this:** Is there a modern, established, and *safe* pattern for surfacing this sort of dynamic query access, or has anyone done something similar and successful they could share with me?

Comment: Several hundred columns is always a Red Flag in my head.  Have you considered an EAV structure?

Comment: I'm considering just about anything at this point. Believe me, that's a concern to me as well. The solution we have is very dated, and we're now running into limits of row size. Were you thinking an EAV built atop SQL? Or a different product altogether>

Comment: In SQL Server.  I suspect you have sparse records.  An EAV approach may actually reduce database size and simplifies your queries to a couple of fields.  The results can always be pivoted if necessary.

Comment: Attempts along those lines haven't been performant enough in the past. These are often called millions of times a day, and you can't get a good cache ratio due the dynamic nature of the requests. EAV is still more or less my top contender for refactoring, but I'm not sure there's a way to efficiently get the data out.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just don't like clutter.  I've had success with EAV, but never applied to millions of hits per day.

Comment: I appreciate the input. I'll play around in that space and see if I can come up with something applicable.